# How to use a version of a gem that has been published on Github but not yet on Rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to install, and use, the `datamapper` gem in my Sinatra application. I am running into an issue where there is a bug in a version of a gem that the `datamapper` gem depends on: the `dm-do-adapter` gem.

I'm not exactly sure how to solve this issue. It looks like the bug has been fixed in the master branch of the gem, but hasn't been tagged yet. So my Gemfile currently looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'datamapper'
gem 'dm-do-adapter', :git => 'git://github.com/datamapper/dm-do-adapter.git'
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. After trying `bundle update`, I get this message:

```
Could not find gem 'dm-core (~> 1.1.1)', required by 'dm-do-adapter', in any of the sources
```

What is the best way to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the `DataObjects::URI.new with arguments is deprecated` warning, then try this:

```
gem 'dm-do-adapter', 
  git: 'git://github.com/datamapper/dm-do-adapter',
  ref: '7f0b53d1ada8735910e0'
```

I just made a new project with the above in my Gemfile and it worked fine.

Comment: Is the bug you are trying to fix the `DataObjects::URI.new with arguments is deprecated` one?

Comment: Yes, and actually, the "bug" that was preventing me from continuing was actually a bug on my end. I failed to specify a primary key on my model which I didn't see because it was hidden below this error.

Comment: Good to know. Still, using that ref of the dm-do-adapter should fix the warning.